# Inheritance - Class.extend()

Tags: javascript

The author of the presentation [here](http://www.slideshare.net/rmurphey/building-large-jquery-applications) uses a construct `Class.extend()`, starting from slide no. 14

Is this coming from any specific library? Or is the author using [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class.extend()` is propriety to some library. JavaScript has the `extends` keyword, so most libraries use `extend` instead.

There is, however, [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). It allows you to construct a new object easily with another object as its prototype.

Comment: Thanks! I am looking for an easy way to achieve Java like inheritance with javascript, I am interested in knowing which js library is providing the construct...

Comment: [John Resign has a pretty cool implementation of classic inheritance in JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/).